Examples of Grothendieck ($\infty$-)topoi which do / do not satisfy the law of excluded middle
I would like to create a big list of Grothendieck topoi (or Grothendieck $\infty$-topoi) which do / do not satisfy the law of excluded middle. That is, let’s list some examples of topoi whose internal logic does / does not validate that inference rule
$$ \overline{P \vee \neg P}$$
IIRC, there is a subtle distinction between double-negation elimination and LEM, but that if we’re talking about the entire topos validating the inference rule, they are equivalent, so we are equivalently asking whether these topoi do / do not validate the inference rule
$$\overline{\neg \neg P \Rightarrow P}$$
So for example, $Set$ (or $Spaces$) does validate this rule, but beyond that I am very fuzzy:

Which presheaf topoi validate LEM?

The sheaf topoi on which topological spaces validate LEM?

$G$-sets for which (topological) groups validate LEM?

…



These are called Boolean topoi. The topoi of presheaves are typically not Boolean. Exception: presheaves on groupoids. The topos of sheaves on a topological space is Boolean if and only if its T_0-fication is a discrete space.

These are exactly the Boolean topoi, see for instance MacLane–Moerdijk, Chapter VI, §1, Proposition 1 and equation (15) in Chapter VI, §6. Since this is a property of the lattice of opens, it only depends on the 0-localic reflection (I suspect the same should be true for $\infty$-topoi, but I don't know the 'logic' interpretation of higher topoi that well).

Also, geometric gros topoi are not Boolean (if there were an excluded middle, then mappings of spaces could be defined piecewise: on a subspace cut out by some condition and its complement)

I am confused, I thought that by HoTT 3.2.2. no ∞-topos satisfy LEM.

@NikolaTomić 3.2.2 disproves $\mathsf{LEM}_\infty$, but the proper version in section 3.4, which concerns only propositions, is consistent.
